# How to select the row in KendoGrid having time column value closest to current time (not date)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid in which one column has appointment time. On Grid load I want to select the row which has time closest to the current time.

*For Example Kendo grid has four rows and each row has following value in Appointment time column:
09:30 AM,
10:30 AM,
11:30 AM,
12:30 AM*

and current time is 11:00 AM. Now on page load, the row having time as 11:30 AM should get selected.

If we load the grid on 12:00 AM then the row having 12:30 AM should get selected.

And if we load the grid after 12:30 AM then last row of grid should get selected since it'll be closest to the current time:

My current code to select the row looks as follows:

Kendo Grid ID: **dgListView**

Kendo Column

```
{
        field: "ApptTime",
        hidden: true,
        template: function (dataItem) {
            return kendo.toString(dataItem.ApptTime, "hh:mm tt")
        },
        attributes: {
            ApptTime: "ApptTime"
        }
    }
```

Function on databound

```
function SetGridRowSelected(e) {
var objGrid = jQuery_1_9_1('#dgListView');
var row;
var currentDate = new Date();

var time = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString();

var data = objGrid.data("kendoGrid");

row = data.tbody.find(">tr:not(.k-grouping-row)").filter(function (i) {
    return (this.cells[18].innerHTML >= time); //18th column in Grid has appointment time
});

if (objGrid && row.length) {
    data.select(row);
    row.click();
    row.addClass('k-state-selected');
}

var scrollContentOffset = grid.find("tbody").offset().top;
var selectContentOffset = data.select().offset().top;
var distance = selectContentOffset - scrollContentOffset;
grid.find(".k-grid-content").animate({
    scrollTop: distance
}, 500);
}
```

I'm comparing the 18th column (it has appointment time) with the current time and trying to select the row which is closest to it but comparison is not happening and it's not throwing any error.

Comment: Can you add some detail as to what is or isn't working in the code you posted, what you have tried, etc?

Comment: I'm comparing the 18th column (it has appointment time) with the current time and trying to select the row which is closest to it but comparison is not happening and it's throwing error.

Comment: What line is throwing the error and what is the error?

Comment: sorry, It's not throwing any error but it's not selecting any rows as well.

Comment: I suggest putting in a debugger line and using your browser dev tools to step through and see what is happening. is your filter selector working and is a row being returned or not? If the innerHTML vs time comparison line is executing what are the values of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the whole example at this [Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/IYUdiXiN/2)

The time within a day can be computed using epoch time modulus *milliseconds in a day* math

```
date.getTime() % 86400000
```

As a page is view the current time is always changing, so you will need to possibly change which row is to be selected

```
        setInterval(function() {
          // note: nowModel is an observable bound to a displayed element
          nowModel.set('now', new Date());
          select_row_next_closest_by_time();
        }, 1000);
```

Selecting the next (forward time) closest to current time requires searching through the data of the grid view.

```
        var seluid;
        function select_row_next_closest_by_time() {
          var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
          var v = grid.dataSource.view();
          var msn = nowModel.get('now').getTime() % 86400000;
          
          var minuid="", mindiff = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
          // scan the view data to find next nearest time point
          for (var index=0; index < v.length; index++) {
             var ms = v[index].get('Date').getTime() % 86400000;
             var diff = ms - msn;
             if (diff < 0) diff += 86400000;  // for wrap around
             if (diff < mindiff) {
               mindiff = diff;                // first next closest in time
               minuid = v[index].uid;
             }
          }

          if (seluid != minuid) {
            // change selection
            if (seluid) { 
              grid.tbody.find('tr[data-uid="'+seluid+'"]').removeClass('k-state-selected');
            }
            grid.select(grid.tbody.find('tr[data-uid="'+minuid+'"]'));
            seluid = minuid;
          }
        }
      });
```

**Alternate way**

Go here for [example Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/oLOyUgax)

Presuming the grid data is presorted by Date, and all the rows in the grid are for the same day, use `.find()` and `.indexOf()` methods to determine which row should be selected.  Of course the methods use looping behind the scene.

```
        var view = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.view();

        nowt = (new Date()).getTime() % 86400000; 
        
        var
          pick = view.find(row => (row.Date.getTime() % 86400000) >= nowt),
          pickIndex = (pick === undefined) ? view.length-1 : view.indexOf(pick)
        ;
        
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").select("tr:eq("+pickIndex+")");
```

Comment: Hi Richard! Your answer is apt and perfect for the updating time. In my case, I need to only consider the time at the page load, after that I don't need to update the grid if the user stays on page for long enough to cross the time on the next row. Next row will only be selected on the next page load.
Is it possible to achieve it without for loop where I don't have to iterate over all the grid rows. Without for loop logic will be like ignore the rows having less time than now and select the next first row since the grid is sorted by ascending time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it working. I'm still looking for if i can make it work without for loop.

Comment: How is the page delivered (what is host server) ? How is the data loaded in the page ?  Not sure why you would expend energy looking for 'non-for loop' search.

Comment: It's a ASP .Net web page and the data is loaded on web page load from Database. I'
m looking for non for loop solution is because the Kendo grid which iIm loading on the page is scrollable non pageable grid which means all the rows from database will be loaded at once in the grid. If there are thousands of rows, it'll have to iterate through all the rows.
Your answer have very much resolved my issue so thanks for that. Could you please update the answer if the current time is greater than time in all the rows in Grid then the last row of the grid should be selected.

Comment: .Net can deliver the page with the row preselected if you add k-state-selected to the row that should be selected.  Regardless, a simplified row selection is now also shown in the answer

Comment: Updated code which you have provided, it breaks saying "row" is undefined.
Here - view.find(row =>

Comment: What browser and version are you using ? The `find` callback is an *arrow function* available in `modern` JavaScript

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 86.0.4240.75.

Comment: See Dojo https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/oLOyUgax should be working there.  If not you'll need to see what is going on in Developer Tools console messages tab.

Comment: Yeah. Your Dojo is working absolutely fine but in my case value of pick is coming as undefined, I checked in the developer tool. It's always selecting 2nd last row because of view.length -1 logic.

Comment: Can you please update your previous dojo to select last row of the grid in case of current time is past all the available time in grid.

Comment: Try taking out the wrap out ` if (diff < 0) diff += 86400000;  // for wrap around`

Comment: I did but it's still selecting the first row.

Comment: No sure what am I missing.

Comment: You'll have to make a Dojo or jsFiddle that reproduces your problem before I can comment further